# Patching Kernel32.dll calls to avoid admin privileges for compatibility

Tags: windows, compatibility, dll, privileges

I am trying to get a really old program for a scientific instrument to run on Windows 10. I believe the program was originally developed for some Unix system, then ported to something like Windows NT by using a Unix emulator. The program worked up to Windows XP, but not on later versions because of changes in security policy.

I would like to upgrade to Windows 10, and I have managed to get the program to run on Windows 10, but only under administrator privileges which I absolutely cannot use on the computer. I know I can run a virtual machine, but I would like to avoid it if I can. I cannot upgrade to a different Unix emulator either since the program and the emulator are so tightly interconnected. Compatibility mode does not work either.

Using API Monitor, I have figured out that the program needs administrator privileges because it tries to create global memory sections which I think is for communication between the emulator and the program and this requires the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` which only administrators have. I cannot grant the privilege to the user account because of security policies.

Using API Monitor, I have tried to insert a breakpoint at the problematic global `Kernel32.dll` calls `CreateFileMappingA`, `CreateSemaphoreA`, `CreateMutexA`, `CreateEventA` and manually change them from global to local which appears to make the program run correctly.

Is there a way to permanently patch/hook/intercept the `Kernel32.dll` calls to be local instead of global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours) or a custom [AppCompat shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711665/windows-how-to-create-custom-appcompat-shims-application-fixes) (if none of the existing ones fit) to override the library calls.

Comment: I think the shims looks really promising. There is a LocalMappedObject fix which fixes the CreateFileMappingA call, but I have to spend some more effort to make it work...

Comment: When I added the DLL calling the offending API to the parameters list of LocalMappedObject fix, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try
[WinAPIOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/index.php) :

> WinAPIOverride is an advanced api monitoring software for 32 and 64 bits processes.
> You can monitor and/or override any function of a process.
> This can be done for API functions or executable internal functions.

The application is free for home non-comercial usage (donationware).
It was last updated on February 2022.

Otherwise, you will need to write your own global system-wide hooking
program which will inject your DLL into the process space and intercept
these system calls.